# only show Typoscript breadcrumb when more then 1

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I try to create a breadcrumb that is only shown subpages. So far I have this code:

```
lib.breadcrumb = HMENU
lib.breadcrumb {
   special = rootline
   special.range = 1|-1
   wrap =  <span class="breadcrumbs">|</span>
   1 = TMENU
   1 {
   noBlur = 1
      NO {
           allWrap =   <span>|</span> 
            stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
         }
      CUR = 1
      CUR {
        doNotLinkIt = 0
        allWrap =   <span class="current">|</span>
        }
      }
}
```

(range is 1 cause 0 is something special).
So on `page1` I don't want to show the breadcrumbs. On `page1.1` that is a subpage from `page1` I want to see th breadcrumb like `page1 > page1.1`.

My Problem is, I don't find a way to only show the breadcrumbs on subpages. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On option would be to use a condition of type [`treeLevel`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#condition-treelevel).

Just wrap your code in:

```
[treeLevel = 2,3,4,5,6,7]
    # ... Your code here
[global]
```

Or clear the menu on levels 0 and 1:

```
[treeLevel = 0,1]
    lib.breadcrumb >
[global]
```